# how to make a conical box shadow flutter

Tags: flutter

I have a circular **Container** that I can move around and I want it to **leave a trail in the shape of a declining cone** like this: [image: coneToBe] 
 And in the future I also want to make this cone become bigger and smaller depending on how fast the circle moves: [image] [image]

This is what I have done: 
[image: myShadow] 
 How do I make a conical trail like the one in red?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

How do I make Trails in Flutter, like in Unity or other game engines?

trail renderer:
https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-TrailRenderer.html

trails module particles
https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PartSysTrailsModule.html

Defold trails
https://forum.defold.com/t/hyper-trails-customizable-trail-effect/48986

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hi, this doesn't seem to answer my question. Doing it in unity is one thing, making the same thing in Flutter is another. I want to make it in Flutter!